# Fatal error: Class name must be a valid object or a string

Tags: 7, entities

A "Fatal error: Class name must be a valid object or a string […] common.inc" appears on every page on the backoffice.

We don't how to reproduce this because it happens suddenly. When I've done a `var_dump()` of `$class`, and `$entity_type`, this is the result I obtained:

```
    string 'user' (length=4)
    TaxonomyTermController
    string 'taxonomy_term' (length=13)
    string 'user' (length=4)
```

The debug code has been added to [entity_get_controller()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/entity_get_controller/7).

```
function entity_get_controller($entity_type) {
  $controllers = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__, array());
  if (!isset($controllers[$entity_type])) {
    $type_info = entity_get_info($entity_type);
    $class = $type_info['controller class'];
    echo $class; 
    var_dump($entity_type);
    $controllers[$entity_type] = new $class($entity_type);
  }

  return $controllers[$entity_type];
}
```

It seems that `$type_info['controller class']` doesn't exist for "User".

This problem is solved when we flush the cache_bootstrap (via `DELETE FROM cache_bootstrap`) and cache (via `DELETE FROM CACHE`), but this is a temporary solution because it appears again.

It's a big problem for us. Any idea will be really appreciated.

Comment: It would be interesting to see the output of `$entities = module_invoke_all('entity_info'); var_export($entities);`.

Comment: Also, as you are not getting the error when you clean the cache, then something could be wrong with the cached data; maybe they are corrupted.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree with you about the corrupted cached data. What origin of this behavior ? Thanks of lot !

Comment: I am getting this same error with nowhere to start looking. I cleared the cache and cache bootstrap tables many times to no avail.

Comment: Can you show the output of the code I reported in the first comment?

Comment: What line throws the error? As you can see there are MANY people having the same kind of problem, but the solutions are different each time: http://drupal.org/search/apachesolr_multisitesearch/class%20name%20common.inc

Comment: Here is more: http://drupal.org/node/1379690#comment-6032428 - I had to get around this but it points to Date filter for me.

Comment: Is it possible that the "user" module has been marked as disabled? That _should_ not be possible under normal circumstances, but check the "status" column in the "system" table for the user entry.

Comment: See if anything is implementing hook_user_load or hook_entity_load (or alter) and corrupting the object. Quick way to see: `egrep -rn "Implements hook_user_load" .`

Comment: Yes, in a custom block on the homepage, mycustomentity_load was being used. Can't do that?

Comment: I truncated all the `cache_' tables and that seemed to have worked, clearing cache with drush failed

Answer (score 0):

The function [entity_get_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/entity_get_info/7) is responsible for gathering up this data about your entities. I would try to debug that one, and see what goes wrong.

You will want to have just cleared the cache when you do this, or you debug results will not be correct.

Can't think of a better answer to the question that is still generic enough to be useful for someone else.

Comment: It was actually errorring out because customentity_load (arg(1)) was being used in a block on the website. I replaced it with entity_load($params)- but this seems like the same path... now that functionality does not work, but the error is gone.